# parallelism repartitions, ordering, and hash matches

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am just starting to delve into query plans and recently learned that "hash matches" are bad.  I know it's rare for something to be so absolute, though, and I want to determine if I have a bad hash match.

My query, which includes two tables, uses parallelism.  It uses clustered index seeks on the two tables then it goes to the step **Parallelism (Repartition Streams)** with partitioning type of hash after both of these seeks.  For one table, a bitmap is created and then these two are joined (inner join) by hash match.

My understanding is if the data to be joined is ordered, a merge join would be used - and this is preferable.  The clustered indexed seek is ordered.

So... I guess I'm just looking for some information on this situation.  Do hash matches always follow repartitions of streams?  Does that repartition ignore order?  Or should I not be bothered by this "evil" hash match?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hash matches are not necessarily bad @ all. Please see Grant Fritchey's awesome (and free!) book: [SQL Server Execution Plans](https://www.simple-talk.com/redgatebooks/grantfritchey/eBOOK_SQLServerExecutionPlans_2Ed_G_Fritchey.pdf)

Comment: +1 - None of the join types are better than the other, they all have their uses and proper use cases.  Hash match is  the most versatile of the three.

Comment: This is a fantastic resource!  You probably just saved me from posting another dozen questions!  :)

Comment: Agreed, I can't believe it's free. Thank you Redgate :)

Answer (score 1):

What you see in that Execution plan is nothing unusual. It's quite common to have these steps in the execution plan when you're dealing with small-large tables. Depending on your SQL Server Edition, you'll either be using bitmap filter or optimized bitmap filter. Both help you, though the optimized one (Enterprise/Developer only) can do some pretty nifty things (elimnating rows -before- the join).

For more details, check out [Optimizing Data Warehouse Query Performance Through Bitmap Filtering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522541.aspx)